# How to generate TextFields dynamically from json Object using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular2 in my project, and i came across some problems to use it,I have an API which returns this JSON Object:

> items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"},...]}

what i want to achieve from this JSON object is (look at this image):
[thats what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkMut.png)

I tried this code, but it doesnt work as expected :

```
<div class="panel-body panelcolor">
     <div *ngFor="let item of items.stations; let i=index, let last = last">

        <div  *ngIf="!last"><span>{{item.station}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items.stations[i+1]">{{items.stations[i+1].station}}</span>
                              <div class="input-group spinner">
                                        <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control" >
                                        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                                        <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                                        <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                              </div>
                                      </div>

                        </div>
                                    <button style="margin-left: 479px;"> Submit </button>
                    </div>
```

this code its gave this result in this picture :[thats what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP4R2.png)

but when i tried to change the price in one generated textbox, all the textboxes are chenged too,i dont know why, i want also when i click the submit button i want to generate this JSON object:

> {"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}],
>   "prices":[{"etape":"New York-->toto","price":"20"},{"etape":"toto-->>titi","price":"10"},
>   {"etape":"titi-->tata","price":"40"},"etape":"tata-->California","price":"65"}]}

can anyone help please to achieve this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

All you need to do is code outside of for loop for your departure to first station and last station to departure

```
<div class="panel-body panelcolor">

    <div *ngIf="items?.departure">
        <span>{{items.departure}}</span> --> 
        <span *ngIf="items.stations.length > 0">
            {{items.stations[0].station}}
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="items.stations.length === 0">
            {{items.arrival}}
        </span>

        <div class="input-group spinner">
            <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div *ngFor="let item of items.stations; let i=index, let last = last">

        <div *ngIf="!last">
            <span>{{item.station}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items.stations[i+1]">{{items.stations[i+1].station}}</span>
            <div class="input-group spinner">
                <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                    <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                    <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div *ngIf="items?.arrival && items?.stations.length > 0">
        <span>{{items.stations[items.stations.length-1].station}}</span> --> <span>{{items.arrival}}</span>
        <div class="input-group spinner">
            <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button style="margin-left: 479px;"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

> For the output result, you have to read about reactive form in
>   angular, by using this you'll be able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: thanks for answer ser, please can u add it to plunker project please?

Comment: @yoyo1236areezd, please create the plunker with your code first, I will make the required changes over there

Comment: i tried your code but it gives me this error:ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'departure' of undefined

Comment: any suggestions please? there was an error in my code i replaces the city by the word station because theres no such thing in the json object anyway, your doesnt work as expected.

Comment: the same error:ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'departure' of undefined, just to remind you heres the json object :items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}]};

Comment: @yoyo1236areezd , pllease try now

Comment: For exact output please create the plunker.

Comment: it works now but the last one doesnt appart..it gives me this:ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'station' of undefined

Comment: i meant tata --> california doesnt appear

Comment: this is it, thank you so mutch for help, but theres one one thing please, why when i change the price in one textbox all the others changes at the same time?

Comment: might be beacuse of formControlName="price"

Comment: yes i know is there any solution to this problem?? i did formControlName="price" to retrieve the value of each textbox

Comment: one more thing ive just noticed why did you use the question mark here <div *ngIf="items?.departure">

Comment: Try to assign dynamic name like station1 station2, or push formelement in formgrouo